# I could not download Spring Tool Suite, seems site is down

Tags: spring, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, suite

I need a help to get Spring Tool Suite for Eclipse (or build in Eclipse). It seems that site is down for several days. Could someone share with me one of latest build of STS for Eclipse or Spring installed in Eclipse?

Thank you!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with programming. Use google to find a mirror, or wait for the site to come back up.

Comment: The site is working perfectly for me. Which one are you using? You find the correct ones at https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

Comment: I tried mirrows, Eclipse Market place - nothing working for me. Also I don't have connection to STS Jira to rise a question. Yes, it is not a question about programming, but stackoverflow was described as a support page for builds. Maybe issue caused by internet provider.. no ideas.

Comment: Yes, this issue was caused by my internet provider strange restrictions.. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: What kind of restrictions and how do solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to download it in Eclipse and it works. Please try Help--> Eclipse Market Place and search Spring Tool Suite. I used Eclipse Mars.2

Comment: I also tried Eclipse Marketplace, different links to mirrows, links to update sites - nothing works for me.

Comment: Yes, this issue was caused by my internet provider strange restrictions.. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: What kind of restrictions and how do you solve it? Thanks